# How to send email by godaddy email account in django?

Tags: python, django, email, smtp, html-email

I want to send mails by my godaddy email account. The function which i have created in veiws.py , That is working perfectly with gmail account but not sending emails from my godaddys' email. Please tell me whats the possible mistake im making here.

views.py(functions to send verifcation code)

```
class SignUp(CreateView):
    form_class = UserCreateForm
    template_name = 'accounts/signup.html'
        
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False # Deactivate account till it is confirmed
            user.save()

            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            subject = 'Activate Your Dotescrow Account'
            html_message = loader.render_to_string('accounts/account_activation_email.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
            })
            user.email_user(subject,'message' ,fail_silently=True,html_message=html_message)
            messages.success(request, 'Please verify you email to activate you account.')
            return redirect('accounts:signup')

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'mail.bussicess.net'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'no-reply@bussicess.net'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
```

If more code is require then tell me in comment sessions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This code is working fine ,I just received emails quite late due to poor internet connect but you guys can you it in django. this code is fine for godaddy emails. Thank You.